# Scoring algorithm user/actions

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm looking for a scoring algorithm but I really don't find what I'm looking for.

Let's imagine an application in which an user can post reviews, can vote on articles or create reviews, like or dislike reviews/articles. The goal is to rank user depending on their activity.

The system himself might grow like a neperian logarithm or something, so the more points you have the more difficulty you have to get more points. Also a newbie must have a voice against a very experienced user, but his voice is less important.

I'm thinking about:

Each action has a base value.

An user has an amount of points, which determines his weight.
His amount of points determine his level and so the set of actions he can perform.

When a user performs an action his weight affect the base value of the action, and his amount of points increase so his weight also.

Does this sound correct ? And Do you know some algorithms/examples of code implementing this kind of thing ? Thanks

PS : I also mean which function should I take has weight ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

Each action has base value at least 100 points (but not more than 1000).

User starts with 100 points

And if user that has **X** points in total performs action with value base **Y** you give him `10 * Y / log2(log2(X))` extra points.

So after performing consecutively actions with 100 base value, user recives:

```
360 points (460 total points)
317 points (777 total points)
306 points (1083 total points)
and so on
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. Yes I think it's the idea. Maybe I can adjust the log so it doesn't go crazy in a 'human time', also I have to define rules, so it's not possible to game the system